# Find original width and height of image while clicking using jQuery

Tags: image

I've multiple images in a page. I want to find width and height of image when clicking it.

I've tried this code:

```
$(body img).click(function(){
  var width = $(this).naturalWidth;
  var height = $(this).natualHeight;
  console.log(width);
  console.log(height);
});
```

But i can't get original width and height of image.

Answer (score 0):

$(this) gives you object, not DOM node. Try this.

```
$("body img").click(function(){
   var width = $(this)[0].clientWidth;
   var height = $(this)[0].clientHeight;
   console.log(width);
   console.log(height);
});
```